# WWW::Mechanize won't work after submit

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

At my work I build a lot of wordpress sites and I also do a lot of cutting and pasting. In order to streamline this process I'm trying to make a crawler that can fill out and submit form information to wordpress. However, I can't get the crawler to operate correctly in the wordpress admin panel once I'm past the login.

I know it works to submit the login form because I've gotten the page back before. But this script doesn't seem to return the "settings" page, which is what I want. I've been trying to use this site as a guide: [www.higherpass.com/Perl/Tutorials/Using-Www-mechanize/3/](http://www.higherpass.com/Perl/Tutorials/Using-Www-mechanize/3/) for how to use mechanize but I could use some additional pointers for this. Here is my Perl script, I've tried a few variations but I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$url2 = 'http://www.moversbatonrougela.com/wp-admin/options-general.php';

$url = 'http://www.moversbatonrougela.com/wp-admin';
$m->get($url);
$m->form_name('loginform');
$m->set_fields('username' => 'user', 'password' => 'password');
$m->submit();

$response = $m->get($url2);
print $response->decoded_content();
```

Comment: even if you could only point me to a better resource on how to use mechanize I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Its pretty well documented, did you check out the [WWW::Mechanize manual](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/49162/favorites?sort=newest)?

Comment: There is a lot of online documentation for WWW::Mechanize.  If you go to http://search.cpan.org and type in "WWW::Mechanize" you'll find the basic POD, an Examples document, a Cookbook document, and a FAQ document.  Due diligence would be diving into those and coming here to seek clarification on whatever points are still unclear.

Comment: The howto you posted doesn't even have `use strict`. I wouldn't trust it too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the below lines of code just before `$m->submit();` . Since `WWW::Mechanize` is a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent` you can use any of LWP's methods.

```
$m->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$m->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });
```

The above would enable logging in your code. Look out for the Request/Response return codes i.e. 200 (OK) or 302 (Redirect) etc. The URL request i.e. the `$m->get()` is probably getting redirected or the machine's ip is Blocked by the server. If its a redirect, then you can probably use `$m->redirect_ok();` to follow the redirect URL, or in case you don't want to follow the redirect URL use `$m->requests_redirectable` (this is an LWP method). The logs should show something like below-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

OR

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

If none of the above works, use an alternative of `$m->submit();` like below and give it a try-

```
 my $inputobject=$mech->current_form()->find_input( undef, 'submit' );
 $m->click_button(input => $inputobject);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give that a try a little later. Very informative. I'll let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: [Here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422917/perl-wwwmechanize-methods-not-working-in-aix is one of my posts when i was facing trouble with click_ok(). This might help as well

Comment: Sorry, I've tried everything you said but to no avail. I thought I had it a while ago but I'm still just getting redirected to a "forgot your password?" page. Thanks for the help though, I'm gonna keep trying.